# Facebook "Share" and "Like" buttons always in English even when I specify another language

Tags: facebook, multilingual, internationalization, social-sharing-buttons

I'm displaying the Facebook share button on my website, but it always displays in English, even though I followed the guidelines for using another language.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=149263621911030&version=v2.0"; 
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

As you can see, I want to have the text for the button in German, but it displays in English anyway.

Here's the funny part: If I substitute `sdk.js` with `all.js` which, [according to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), is deprecated, everything works fine. This is true for at least Swedish, German and Danish, which are the only ones I've tested so far.

Should I be doing something differently to get things to work with the recommended `sdk.js`, or did Facebook just ditch support for other languages than English in the latest version?

For completeness, the part where I display the Share-button looks like this:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://adrdangerousgoods.com/ger/" data-width="250" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: To me it looks like you got it right, based on facebook localization docs.  Do you have a meta tag which defines at UTF charset or language for the page?

Comment: For Reference:  https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

Comment: Look at this StackOverflow Answer by David L.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827726/how-to-change-language-of-fb-like-button   Looks like the user who is viewing your site needs to have their language set to German for it to work.

Comment: Another interesting sample of using the iframe code (for likes and shares) to force a language.http://codepen.io/marktopper/pen/eHzis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869555/david-l) says in [How can the language of the Facebook "like" button be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827726/how-to-change-language-of-fb-like-button):

> ... the language pointed out in the URL, is for the DEFAULT language of the text. However, if a person has her/his Facebook account already open, such setting is superseded by the default language of THE ACCOUNT'S language. But that will change according to each individual's own settings, which is a desirable behavior.

So while you are specifying the default language for the button, it is always coming up as English for *you* because you are signed into Facebook with an account set to English as the preferred language.  To test it, use private browsing so that it can't access your Facebook account.